# Is a .byte array the same as declaring an .asciz string literal?

Tags: arrays, assembly, att

This may seem like an odd question, but does x64 treat arrays declared as .byte segments the same as .asciz arrays? The context is that I’m reading in a string using the read system call (just to see if I can). I store this in a buffer array of type .byte. Though, if I try to print this array out to standard out via printf, it does not print anything. So, my question is, in essence, do I need to do something different in this case?

Comment: In assembly, everything is just raw bytes.  It doesn't matter what directive you use to output those bytes, just what the assembler emits into the output file.  e.g. `.byte 0x90` and `nop` are identical anywhere, even in `.section .data.`  And yes,  `.byte` and `.asciz` can emit the same data if you give them the corresponding args.  Normally you wouldn't use either of those for an input buffer, though.  If you showed a [mcve] of your actual problem, we could tell you what's wrong with it, but running it under `strace ./a.out` usually helps.

Comment: @PeterCordes Would I, instead, use the .space directive for an input buffer?

Comment: Sure, that would be a good choice to reserve multiple bytes in `.bss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with one exception: A `.byte` array doesn't put a null terminator at the end for you like `.asciz` does.

```
.asciz "Hello"
```

is the same as:

```
.byte 0x48,0x65,0x6C,0x6C,0x6F,0x00
```

This goes even further than that, however. For example, `.word 0x1234` is treated identical to `.byte 0x34,0x12` (assuming a little-endian architecture, which x86 is.) For clarity purposes it's best to declare your data with its intended type, but it's not required like it would be in C. (Some assemblers have an issue with it, but at runtime, all bets are off.)